# Mysql Connector C++ and floats

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I can't find anything about getting floats from a result set or how to store floats in a prepared statement to create a query in order to insert the float number.
Is it possible to do this? Should I store them using a char array?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For result retrieval, I expect you use `ResultSet::getDouble` - for statements, `PreparedStatement::setDouble`.

There does not seem to be accommodation for `float` specifically, but the underlying column definition will be `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I seem to have a problem using getDouble(), using a table like with lat and lon as doubles:
  while (res->previous()) {
    cout << "Printing Row" << res->getInt("id") << "|" << res->getDouble("lat") << "|" << res->getDouble("lon") << endl;
  }
Gets me a:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::InvalidArgumentException'
  what():  MySQLPreparedResultSet::getDouble: invalid 'columnIndex'
Which only happens when I try to retrieve the lat or lon columns.

Comment: That's pretty bad, perhaps you *do* have to use strings and convert back and forth.  Have you tried doing it that way?

Comment: I don't see that strings are necessary, the source code seems to allow the double to be gotten. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/trunk/view/head:/driver/mysql_ps_resultset.cpp - are you sure the column IDs are correct?

Comment: Woops, I was selecting only the id. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: great, at least this encouraged me to track down the source code ;-)